# how to get the largest sum of indexes in array that have a negative numbers in java

Tags: java, arrays

hy , i'm a beginner java student and we were asked to take the sequence of indexes with the largest sum , the array have negative and positive  numbers and may contain 0
our job is to get the largest sum of indexes that are in a row and it can be one index , with method not with algorithm because we haven't learned that yet
thank you for your help

Comment: so you want us to do your homework in your place?

Comment: Try something and comeback with your findings, from that the community can start helping you.

Comment: It's good that you were asked to do such an interesting exercise.  What is your question?

Comment: well i dont want u to do the homework for but it did seems like it so im sorry for that , and ok i will comeback with something more suitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to do your homework for you but here's some tips:

1. How do you know if a sequence is the largest?
2. When should you stop counting a sequence?
3. If the next number in the sequence is a negative is your sum getting larger?
4. How would you brute force this problem?
5. Do you have to brute force it? (No. Look at points 2 and 3 and think about it)

You should be able to figure it out from the questions above. If not I would definitely go ask your professor to get some help.

Now that you've figured it out, here are some questions to further your understanding:

6. What if I only wanted the largest 3 numbers in a row? 5? 7?
7. What if all of the numbers are negative? Positive?

If the parameters for question 5 and 6 were added into your question, even though you might think that they narrow down the problem, it actually makes it much harder to solve because of the constraints. This is why we need algorithms, so that we can solve problems with a set of constraints without having to brute force.

Comment: well thank u for those tips it did help to focus my thinking , and our professor want us to think about it before he teaches us the right way to solve it

Comment: public static int maxArray(int[] A) {
        int newSum = A[0];
        int max = A[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
            newSum = Math.max(newSum + A[i], A[i]);
            max = Math.max(max, newSum);
        }

        return max ;


what do you think?

Comment: I think you've got it! Nicely done!

Comment: thanks man i appreciate it